# JQuery's Contains returns an Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to see if a particular string appears in a div. I have tried but it doesn't return true or false which is what I thought contains did?

```
if($("#path"+i+"_status:contains('!=')")){

     alert($("#path"+i+"_status:contains('!=')"));

    //alerts - [object object]

     return true;

}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="status" id="path3_status">
<img height="21" align="absmiddle" src="images/valid.jpg">Text File (3000) = Source Table (3000)<img height="21" align="top" src="images/info.jpg" " id="img_path3">
<a onclick="clear_file('TI004OBAE', 'path3');" href="#">Clear</a>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong. How can I find out if a div contains the string "!="?

Thanks all for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [`contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) is a jQuery selector. Selectors return jQuery object instances, which maintain an array of references to the matched DOM elements.

Check [jQuery's `length` property](http://api.jquery.com/length/) to see whether a selector matched at least one element:

```
if ($("#path"+i+"_status:contains('!=')").length > 0) {
    alert("found a match");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Jeff. A quick question, does `contains` only look at text within elements and not html within elements?

Comment: My pleasure! Yes - `contains` only looks at text within elements, not the markup.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing here `$("#path"+i+"_status:contains('!=')")` is *selecting* an element with that ID and that contains `'!='`.

You could do something like

```
if($("#path"+i+"_status:contains('!=')").length > 0)
```

or

```
if($("#path"+i+"_status").text().indexOf("!=") != -1)
```

This isn't tested but should give you the basic idea.

*Edit - see [Jeff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731571/jquerys-contains-returns-an-object/2731644#2731644) for clarification on why the first example works.

Answer (score 0):

It might just be easier to use the class instead of the ID:

```
 $('.status:contains("!=")').each(function(){
  alert( $(this).text() );
 })
```

Comment: Though it's easier to just use the class, you should always use an id if one is available - for speed and efficiency. (Which definitely matter in contemporary browsers!)